# How to not open another form just to press a button like pressing button ALARM

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm making a Clock application in c#.

How to not open other form just to view something like going to ***ALARM*** or ***STOPWATCH*** or ***TIMER***.

Like when i press Timer then that highlighted area where the gui occurs do some program.

[image]

Comment: Please explain more what you want to achieve. It would be better with some code.

Comment: Consider using a TabControl?

Comment: Okay, when i PRESS STOPWATCH the PANEL will display the components of STOPWATCH like the buttons of START AND STOP. AND if I press the TIMER the panel will clear the STOPWATCH component and OPEN the TIMER components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking that you don't want to open a new windows when you want to use a new form. Do this;

1. When you start making the windows form application. First add a 'Panel', on which you will put all your label, buttons, and stuff.
2. Then add another panel over it, where you want to keep your other labels, buttons, and stuff.
3. On runtime, keep panel1.BringToFront(). So, you will see that panel and work on that one.
4. Then if you want to access another form, instead on form2.Open(). You can just use panel2.BringToFront().

By this method you can have multiple panels on the same form with which you can play with without the need to open another form.

Comment: So I'll use panel to access the form?
Like when i press Alarm the panel will display all the components of alarm and so does the others?

Comment: exactly!! on the other panel, put all the components of alarm. When you click on Alarm, then bring that panel to front using panel2.BringToFront()

Comment: Hi Tanveer, Thanks for your advise, and also i have problem now. I have **3 PANELS** and then the issue is the bringtofront not really working all.

Comment: Hi, once u have used a panel then send that panel to back as, panelname.SendToBack(). Then call the desired panel to front as, panelname.BringToFront().